# VBScript app error log using errorhandler

Tags: vbscript

I need to output all of the information on an error that has occured to a msgbox and a log text file. My current code only outputs a message that tells the user an error has occurred. I need actualy error information to be displayed in short in the msgbox and a more detailed explanation in a log file.

I would just like to add I am using TestPartner for this script and it uses VBScript as its language so the concepts are similar to those in VB6.

This is my code currently:

```
Private Sub CmdPOstart_Click()

errorcount = 0

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Do stuff...

ErrorHandler:
    errorcount = errorcount + 1 'Add 1 to the error count
    'Output the error information to a msgbox
    MsgBox ("An Error Occurred! " & errorcount & " Errors ")
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I retagged and edited the question because VBScript is similar to VB6, but there are some important differences.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/208005/15639) and perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908042/how-to-add-a-log-to-my-vbscript/15908693#15908693) for advice on how to log from VBScript

Comment: In fact, are you sure this is VBScript? `On Error Goto` is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(v=vs.84).aspx) in VBScript. This is an example of the important differences between VB6 and VBScript that I mentioned above.